# Appending an array to an array

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am trying to append the elements in an array to an existing (empty) array

```
if(attributes.list != "")           attributes.array.append(attributes.list.ListToArray());
```

What I get is something like

[image]

Is there a way to do this without having too loop through each item?

Comment: If the target array is empty, a simple ListToArray will suffice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [optional `merge` parameter](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/arrayappend.html):

> If set to true, and value parameter is an array, appends array
>   elements individually to the source array. If false (default) the
>   complete array is added as one element at the end, in the source
>   array. If value is not an array this argument is ignored.

Setting `merge=true` will append the elements individually, rather appending the whole array as a single element:

```
attributes.array.append(attributes.list.ListToArray(), true);
```

[image: ArrayAppend(array, merge) Example]